# Проблема при установке GUI на VPS

Tags: linux, centos, vps, centos7, xfce

Надеюсь вы сможете помочь мне решить мою проблему.

Характеристики VPS:

- 4 vCore
- 6 gb Ram
- 6 gb Swap
- Centos 7 64x

Проблема заключается в том что после установки различных GUI и ребута я не могу приконектиться к машине через ssh. Однако можно открыть доп сессию ssh которую предоставляют на панели управления vps, однако оно ограничено по времени и не является решением проблемы, нопозволяет убедится что машина продолжает работу даже после установки gui.  Поддержка подсказала что они не занимаются консультацией по софту.

Цитата "Well, that's fun of user software installs - we don't support debugging such."

---

Опишу поэтапно мои шаги.

p. s. Все действия проходят на чистой системе.

1. yum -y install epel-release
2. yum -y update
3. yum install -y xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-utils xorg-x11-fonts-* xorg-x11-apps xorg-x11-server-Xorg
4. Затем обычные действия для x11 forwading и проверка соответственно, все работает.
5. yum -y groupinstall "X Window system"
6. yum -y groupinstall xfce
7. systemctl set-default graphical.target
8. init 6

И все, после ребута я не могу приконектиться к машине. Надеюсь на вашу помощь господа

Comment: если есть возможность повторить пройденное прежде, чем перезагрузить сервер, прорвете статус `sshd`. И мне кажется CentOS-7 уже с `systemd` Проверте что требует `sshd.service` для запуска, может условие не выполняется  или ожидается запуска другого сервиса. Так же проверте не добавляются ли блокирующие цепочки `iptables`

Comment: Iptables и Firewall отключены на момент экспериментов с установкой GUI. Сделал как вы предложили. И залил статус sshd.service в различных этапах. Ознакомиться можно тут: https://pastebin.com/eyPFkdh3

Comment: UPD
Сейчас попробовал проделать все кроме ребута и сразу приконектиться через VNC все работает. Однако если ребутнуться то снова нет возможности конектнуться.

Comment: глянте, что у вас требует sshd.service для запуска `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` и еще вариант, что после GUI система вообще не грузится и не доходит дело до sshd

Comment: в том то и дело что она работает, если я конекчусь из резервной консоли который хост предоставляет для отладки, и из консоли видно что ssh продолжает работать после этого, я это продемонстрировал на pastebin (последний пункт после ребута)

Comment: ок, тогда что до и после выдает эта команда `sudo iptables-save | grep -- "--dport 22"`

Comment: Выводит это
`-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

Comment: То что выше мною написано, это выводит уже из резервной консоли. Когда же система работает нормально, команда просто исполняется.